# Why isn't frame of reference called reference point?

Tags: classical-mechanics, reference-frames, terminology, conventions

A frame of reference is the perspective you have on a happenstance. But isn't it a viewpoint or point of view? As in, a literal point, from which something is observed?

If so, why is it called a frame and not a point? Does frame of reference literally crops a section of existence as the perspective of observation?

Why is it one phrasing over another?

Comment: Because a single point alone is not at all sufficient. A frame of reference should conjure that it is a network of observers at rest with each other, having all the axes aligned and setup properly, ready to capture data, even if it is made only by one observer in the end.

Comment: A frame of reference is not a point; it is a 4-tuple of tangent vectors.

Comment: @WillO could you please elaborate on this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are many ways in physics to define a [frame of reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frame_of_reference) and one often understands by context what exactly is meant by the use of this term.

For example, a [rotating frame of reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotating_reference_frame) is one characterized by a certain angular frequency $\omega$ with respect to another frame of reference. It is certainly not the case in this example then, that it is only one point that characterizes this relation, because if you spin a bucket full of water, every molecule of water in that bucket will be affected by the rotation of the bucket, hence there is no preferred point in this rotating bucket frame that goes through this rotation.

In practically all other usages too, a frame of reference implies that there is a definite relation of an entire *system* of coordinates with respect to another one. Another example would be [inertial frames of reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inertial_frame_of_reference) which are related to each other by some fixed linear speed $v$. Again, if a car is driving on the road with a certain speed, this is telling us something about the relation of the entire car to the road. *All* passengers that happen to be in the car will agree that the road is moving past them with the same speed, which is equal in magnitude and opposite in sign to the speed of the car. So this relation is true for the car as a whole and not only for a specific point within the car.

Comment: so if I understand this correctly, the frame of reference is called as such because the measurements aren't done based on a single point, but based on an entire frame, as many situations will have a full kaleidoscope perspective of an event that is not limited to a single point. I don't know how clear my own explanation is, but is this more or less it, then?

Comment: (1/2) A frame of reference is first and foremost a mathematical tool. So it doesn't necessarily correspond with how we actually perform measurements, but rather, with how we carry out calculations that *predict* the outcome of measurements. To go back again to the example of the rotating frame of reference: it may be complicated to perform a certain calculation in the lab's frame which is non-rotating, but mathematically more straightforward to calculate a certain quantity in the rotating frame.

Comment: (2/2) Then, to compare this calculation with the experimental result, one must *transform back* (which just means another mathematical manipulation which is usually straightforward) to the lab frame and hence obtain an agreement or disagreement with the lab's measured value. So again you see, it is the transformation properties of a frame of reference that's important -- relating two states of motion in a way that make it easy to then also relate and compare theoretical predictions to measured values by transforming between the frames.

Answer (score 3):

A frame of reference is not a point; it is mostly a coordinate system. Which direction is X, which direction is Y, which direction is Z, and which point has coordinates 0,0,0. Every coordinate point will be measured according to this frame. You can also make it vary in time, i.e. by adding a velocity or angular velocity, which applies to all points, not just a specific point.

Answer (score 0):

Given a point, several reference frames can be defined. The simplest: either the reference frame is rotating about itself or it is stationary.